# Pip packages updated log

Tags: python, update, ubuntu-20.04, pip

A few days ago I updated all pip packages on Ubuntu 20.04 with this command:

```
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Does exists any way to see previous and present versions of any of them? Is it possible to recover? Some of them are incompatible with some Openstack services now...

Thanks,

Best

Comment: Restore from your backup.

Comment: I have a tar file as backup. Can you help me? I'm new with this and I don't understand very well this documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR